# Generate cert.pem and key.pem on Windows

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to generate a `cert.pem` and `key.pem` files to encrypt http requests with Nginx.

On Linux, I would execute the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes \
          -out ./nginx/config/cert.pem \
          -keyout ./nginx/config/key.pem -days 365
```

What would be an equivalent command to generate such files on Windows?
I have followed this guide but it only generates a `.crt` and `.key` files instead.

https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015960428-How-to-Generate-a-Self-Signed-Certificate-and-Private-Key-using-OpenSSL

Comment: If you install openssl onto windows then it's the same command.

Comment: @ShanePowell Or in WSL :)

Comment: @Alexis so rename privateKey.key to key.pem and certificate.crt to cert.pem. It should work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collecting answers from the comments above:

> If you install openssl onto windows then it's the same command.

Or

> Rename privateKey.key to key.pem and certificate.crt to cert.pem. It should work just fine

Or

I have also created an OpenSSL Docker container which allows to generate certificates without needing to install OpenSSL on Windows or Linux (assuming you have Docker already installed): https://github.com/alexisrolland/docker-openssl